# Appending tuples as values to existing keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of lists, each list has 3 items in it (for the sake of the example): product type, product color, quantity of product.

What I'm trying to do is to create a dictionary in a way that each product type is a key, and the color and quantities are values. That is, what I'm looking for is this structure:

key1:(tuple1),(tuple2),...

or

key1:[(tuple1),(tuple2),...]

The thing is, as you know, you can't really append tuples as values to keys in dicts.

Here's a simple example to play around with:

```
my_list = [["ball","red",2],["ball","blue",5],["ball","green",7],["shirt","large",5],["shirt","medium",9],["shirt","small",11]]

inventory_dict = {}

for item in my_list:
    if item[0] not in inventory_dict:
        inventory_dict[item[0]] = (item[1],item[2])
    else:
        inventory_dict[item[0]].append((item[1],item[2]))
```

When I tried to do something like:

```
my_list = [["ball","red",2],["ball","blue",5],["ball","green",7],["shirt","large",5],["shirt","medium",9],["shirt","small",11]]

inventory_dict = {}

for item in my_list:
    my_tuple = (item[1],) + tuple(item[2])
    if item[0] not in inventory_dict:
        inventory_dict[item[0]] = my_tuple
    else:
        inventory_dict[item[0]].append(my_tuple)
```

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454008/2594546) I got a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" error.

and when I tried to replace my_tuple with:

```
my_tuple = list((item[1],item[2]))
```

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10301630/2594546) I got a result I can't work with, of this form:

```
{'ball': ['red', 2, ['blue', 5], ['green', 7]],
 'shirt': ['large', 5, ['medium', 9], ['small', 11]]}
```

the reason I can't work with it is that for example the len of each value is 4 where it should be 3. The first type and its quantities are separate elements of the value list.

I should mention that in the next step of my code I plan on doing some asthmatics with the quantities.

Hope I was able to explain my problem well enough and hope you can help!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the line in your first example to:

```
inventory_dict[item[0]] = [(item[1],item[2])]
```

If you want to be able to append things later, you need to make the value a list the first time you create it.

You could also use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which would let you just do:

```
inventory_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

and then you can dispense with the if-then and just do the loop like this:

```
for item in my_list:
    inventory_dict[item[0]].append((item[1], item[2]))
```

Comment: arrrrggggg!!! I was so close!! :) Can you imagine how much time I spent trying to figure it out, trying to find the answer, and even writing this question, and the solution was right there! *stupid stupid stupid*

Comment: @Optimesh: Heh, don't be too hard on yourself.  Anybody's eyes will tend to glaze over looking at that many nested brackets and parentheses :-)

Comment: Thanks man. :) Any idea why simple importing "from collections import defaultdict" won't work ('collections not defined') but import collections does ?

Comment: @Optimesh: If you use `from collections import defaultdict` then you need to refer to `defaultdict` as just `defaultdict`.  If you use `import collections` then you need to refer to it as `collections.defaultdict`.  You can find other questions about this on StackOverflow.

Comment: yea, definitely time to go to sleep. :) (1:15 am) Thanks again!!